# Does the rate of decay of an entire function dictates the global growth rate?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is entire and we assume a decay rate on $\mathbb{R}^+$, does this dictate a growth rate on $\mathbb{C}$?

For example, can there be an entire function that decays exponentially on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and it has polynomial growth on $\mathbb{C}$?

Similarly, is there a function that decays as $e^{-x^2}$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and is of exponential type?